# In JavaScript (Node.JS), how do I parse a value like '202111031437' to output date?

Tags: javascript, date, date-parsing

Have previously tried to use Date.parse() but 'undefined' is returned.

```javascript
let datetime = '202111031437';
let parse = Date.parse(datetime);
console.log(parse);
```

Solved the query:

```
const dateParser = (dateString) => {
  const year = dateString.substring(0, 4);
  const month = dateString.substring(4, 6);
  const day = dateString.substring(6, 8);
  const hour = dateString.substring(8, 10);
  const min = dateString.substring(10, 12);
  const dateConcat = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + min;
  const dateTime = new Date(dateConcat);

  return dateTime;
}
```

Comment: Is this `YYYYMMDDhhmm`? You can use a regex `/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/`

Answer (score 1):

```
let datetime = '202111031437';
let year = datetime.substring(0, 4);
let month = datetime.substring(4, 6);
let day = datetime.substring(6, 8);
let hour = datetime.substring(8, 10);
let minute = datetime.substring(10, 12);
console.log(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute));
```